# google.visualization.LineChart is not loading second time

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, google-visualization

I am working on Angular/ionic Cordova project. I am using google.visualization.LineChart to display the chart in my project. First time when we come on the page where I have draw the chart, It is working properly. But when I further navigate to next ion-view and came back to the screen where I have drawn the chart, chart does not appear. Any idea why it is happening? here is my code:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>',
        noBackdrop:false
    });
    serverRepo.salesMonthly().then(function(objS){
            $scope.monthlyData=objS.data;
            if(objS.data.orders == null){
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                alert('There is not data regarding Monthly Sale');
            }else{
                angular.forEach(objS.data.orders, function(value, key) {
                    objS.data.orders[key].CreatedOn=new Date(objS.data.orders[key].CreatedOn);
                    if(key == objS.data.orders.length-1){
                        $scope.data = objS.data;
                        drawChart();
                        console.log('drawChart Called');
                    }
                })
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            }

        },function(objE){
            console.log("Error:-\n"+JSON.stringify(objE));
            $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
});

function drawChart(){
    var options = {
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        curveType: 'function',
        titlePosition: 'in',
        axisTitlesPosition: 'in',
        hAxis: {
            textPosition: 'in',
            minValue: 0,
            textStyle:{color: "#fff"}
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 13,
            textPosition: 'in',
            textStyle:{color: "#fff"},
            minorGridlines:{color: "#ccc"}
        },
        lineWidth: 6,
        fontSize:11,
        chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width: '100%', height: '100%',backgroundColor: '#43396D'},
        colors: ['#32BD76'],
        animation:{
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'out',
            startup: true
        }
    };
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( function () {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'labels');
        data.addColumn('number', 'data');
        for(i = 0; i < $scope.data.labels.length; i++)
            data.addRow([$scope.data.labels[i], $scope.data.datasets.data[i]]);
        // Create and draw the visualization.
        $scope.myChart=new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chartmonthly'));
        $scope.myChart.draw(data, options);
        console.log('chart drawn.......');
    });

}
```

Comment: is `drawChart Called` on second time? try moving code inside `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` into `drawChart` and call `drawChart` from `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback`

Comment: Yes drawnChart called second time also. Still facing same problem. Second time when I came back to the screen, chart did not drawn.

Answer (score 0):

*think* the problem has to do with `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback`

which is called once per page load

try moving the code inside the callback to `drawChart`

then call `drawChart` from the callback

see following example...

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>',
        noBackdrop:false
    });
    serverRepo.salesMonthly().then(function(objS){
            $scope.monthlyData=objS.data;
            if(objS.data.orders == null){
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                alert('There is not data regarding Monthly Sale');
            }else{
                angular.forEach(objS.data.orders, function(value, key) {
                    objS.data.orders[key].CreatedOn=new Date(objS.data.orders[key].CreatedOn);
                    if(key == objS.data.orders.length-1){
                        $scope.data = objS.data;
                        drawChart();
                        console.log('drawChart Called');
                    }
                })
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            }

        },function(objE){
            console.log("Error:-\n"+JSON.stringify(objE));
            $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
});

function drawChart(){
    var options = {
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        curveType: 'function',
        titlePosition: 'in',
        axisTitlesPosition: 'in',
        hAxis: {
            textPosition: 'in',
            minValue: 0,
            textStyle:{color: "#fff"}
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 13,
            textPosition: 'in',
            textStyle:{color: "#fff"},
            minorGridlines:{color: "#ccc"}
        },
        lineWidth: 6,
        fontSize:11,
        chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width: '100%', height: '100%',backgroundColor: '#43396D'},
        colors: ['#32BD76'],
        animation:{
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'out',
            startup: true
        }
    };

    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'labels');
    data.addColumn('number', 'data');
    for(i = 0; i < $scope.data.labels.length; i++)
        data.addRow([$scope.data.labels[i], $scope.data.datasets.data[i]]);
    // Create and draw the visualization.
    $scope.myChart=new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chartmonthly'));
    $scope.myChart.draw(data, options);
    console.log('chart drawn.......');
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: At first this will give error because google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); will execute first then API will be called(written in ionic enter). So It will not get required data i.e. $scope.data.labels. But I have made change and called google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart) inside the service success response, but still same issue I got.

Comment: what happens if you remove `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` altogether?

Comment: Means, I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I resolve change the ID reference for a class.

Ex: 
 to

After, identify the element with jquery: 
from document.getElementById('your_chart_id') to $('.your_chart_id')[0]