# Error: Row given with size different than 4 (the number of columns in the table)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, charts, google-visualization, ngcordova

I am getting

> Error: Row given with size different than 4 (the number of columns in the table).

While coming on the screen where I have implemented Google Chart. Code for creating the chart is:

```
var chartDom=document.getElementById('curve_chartyearly');
var mapObj= new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDom);
data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var options = {
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            curveType: 'function',
            titlePosition: 'in',
            axisTitlesPosition: 'in',
            hAxis: {
                textPosition: 'in',
                minValue: 0,
                textStyle:{color: "#fff"}
            },
            vAxis: {
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 13,
                textPosition: 'in',
                textStyle:{color: "#fff"},
                minorGridlines:{color: "#ccc"}
            },
            lineWidth: 6,
            fontSize:11,
            chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width: '100%', height: '100%',backgroundColor: '#43396D'},
            colors: ['#32BD76'],
            animation:{
                duration: 1500,
                easing: 'out',
                startup: true
            }
        };
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                    data1.addColumn('string', 'labels');
                    data1.addColumn('number', 'data');
                    for(i = 0; i < objS.data.labels.length; i++){
                        data1.addRow([objS.data.labels[i],objS.data.datasets.data[i]]);
                    }
                    $timeout(function(){
                        mapObj.draw(data1, options);
                    },1500)
                });
```

I have checked my logs. `objS.data.labels[i] and objS.data.datasets.data[i]]`

These are coming right with length 12(in my case). I don't know why I am getting that error and how to resolve. Please help..

Comment: are you calling `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` twice?

Comment: No, I am calling google.charts.setOnLoadCallback on page load. Problem is occurring when I further navigate to next page and came back.

Comment: move `data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();` to inside of `setOnLoadCallback()`

Comment: Now I am not getting this error but my chart is not drawn when I came back on the screen.

Comment: Please try to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177882/google-visualization-linechart-is-not-loading-second-time